# How to see response output of API using curl?

Tags: curl

I executed the below API from the command prompt successfully. However, I don't see any output like below I can see using postman.

```
cache-control →no-cache
date →Sun, 06 Oct 2019 07:49:48 GMT
expires →Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
pragma →no-cache
server →Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-session →1390f9b0-6f1a-454a-a96e-d9ce63672a10
x-frame_options →SAME ORIGIN 

curl -XPOST "http://<host_address>/system/ws/authentication/user/login" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Accept-Language: en-US" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d "{"userName": abc,"password": xxx}"
```

I am expecting API output as below -

```
cache-control →no-cache
date →Sun, 06 Oct 2019 07:49:48 GMT
expires →Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
pragma →no-cache
server →Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-session →1390f9b0-6f1a-454a-a96e-d9ce63672a10
x-frame_options →SAME ORIGIN
```

Comment: Add the -i parameter

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the -i parameter to the curl call.

Cf. https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html